# Composer Path Repositories without a package manager

Tags: php, composer-php

Since composer merge plugin is deprecated and the alternative is use of composer path repositories I found a problem transitioning to the later.

My structure is:

```
/composer.json

/local/composer.json
```

Where /composer.json is main composer with all setup and /local/composer.json is a file managing only private repositories.

Contents of each file are:

```
#/composer.json
{
    "name": "main/project",
    "type": "project",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "local"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "sub/project": "dev-main"
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

- 

```
 #/local/composer.json
    {
        "name": "sub/project",
        "autoload": {},
        "repositories": {
            "test_repo": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "git@github.com:rotari/test_repo.git"
            }
        },
        "require": {
            "rotari/test_repo": "dev-main"
        }
    }
```

As you can see the plan is simple: main composer requires sub/project and sub/project requires rotari/test_repo. However on install I'm prompted with error

```
sub/project dev-main requires rotari/test_repo dev-main -> could not be found in any version
```

Running composer install in /local is a success so there is no problem accessing rotari/test_repo.

Any idea or suggestions how this issue could be solved?

Comment: Perhaps the plan is not simple but just wrong? At least the `./composer.json#/repositories/0/url` points to `./local/composer.json` that does not have that package (it has `sub/project`. not `rotari/test_repo`), you need to provide the correct path to a package. Compare with the docs: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path -- have you tried adding another `path` repository with `url` being `local/vendor/rotari/test_repo` ? What happened?

Comment: That would mean for me to pull everything local first (even if I have them in git already) and them reference them individually. Not something was planing to do although it is doable.

Comment: Not even doable. 

Sub Project still has a dependency on rotari/test_repo that can not be resolved.

Comment: Well for the baseline comment on your plans, please see my first comment. And sure you have to have one repository for each package if you use path. Educate yourself in the documentation with the tooling before complaining about not seeing it doable.

Comment: Got it now. Composer is not able to load repositories recursively thus I have to fetch them all into main composer file.

Answer (score 0):

This part from documentation answers my quetion:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-cant-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md

Composer in not able to load repositories recursively.